# Concatenar colunas no SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Preciso concatenar 3 colunas em uma linha utilizando o SQL Server, quando faço a concatenação ele me retorna esse valor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Teria que ficar:

Moura 105ah térreo

Já vi alguns exemplos na internet, porém não consegui associa-los ao meu problema, alguém consegue me ajudar?

Segue a Query que estou fazendo:

```
SELECT CONCAT(TA.asset, TA.techCharacteristic, TA.VALUE, T.meterUnit) AS COLUNAS
        FROM AssetTechChar AS TA
        INNER JOIN TechCharacteristic AS T
        ON TA.techCharacteristic = T.techCharacteristic
        WHERE TA.company = 'TFLM'
        AND asset='F.SP.SJIR.JI.FCC1.BAT01'
        AND TA.techCharacteristic IN ('BAT-003 ', 'BAT-005 ','BAT-002 ')
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Qual a versão do seu `SQL Server`?

Comment: A versão do meu SQL Server é 2017 @Sorack

Comment: Estes valores que você listou estão em campos diferentes ou é o mesmo campo em linhas diferentes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TA.asset + '' + TA.techCharacteristic + '' + TA.VALUE + '' + T.meterUnit AS COLUNAS
  FROM AssetTechChar AS TA
 INNER JOIN TechCharacteristic AS T ON TA.techCharacteristic = T.techCharacteristic
 WHERE TA.company = 'TFLM'
   AND asset='F.SP.SJIR.JI.FCC1.BAT01'
   AND TA.techCharacteristic IN ('BAT-003 ', 'BAT-005 ','BAT-002 ');
```

Para concatenar colunas utilize o caractere `+`. É importante salientar que se alguma das suas colunas possuir `NULL` como valor, toda o texto será transformado em `NULL`.

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!!