# Erro ao converter tipo de dados varchar em float

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

tenho um stored procedure para alterar um campo de tabelas de nome variado:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_alterarCrachaCadAce
--PARÂMETROS
@NomeTabela VARCHAR(20),
@CrachaDestino FLOAT,
@CrachaOrigem FLOAT


AS
BEGIN



Declare @Comando Varchar(1000)

Set @Comando = 'UPDATE '+@NomeTabela +' SET ace_ cracha = '+@CrachaDestino+ ' WHERE ace_cracha = '+@CrachaOrigem

Exec(@Comando)



END
```

porém ele está dando um erro que não entendi muito bem ao executar o sp:

```
Mensagem 8114, Nível 16, Estado 5, Procedimento usp_alterarCrachaCadAce, 

Linha 17
Erro ao converter tipo de dados varchar em float.
```

OBS: o dado que está sendo passado é DOUBLE, porém não achei nenhuma forma de declarar double no SQL, então pelo que entendi devo usar o float mesmo.

Comment: Relacionada: [Concatenar colunas no SQL SERVER](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/370243/concatenar-colunas-no-sql-server/370245#370245) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para concatenar um tipo numérico à um texto você deve convertê-lo para texto, senão o banco de dados tentará realizar uma soma:

```
SET @comando = 'UPDATE ' + @NomeTabela + ' SET ace_ cracha = ' + CAST(@CrachaDestino AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' WHERE ace_cracha = ' + CAST(@CrachaOrigem AS VARCHAR(100));
```

Comment: Perfeito! Quando executado o sp direto no Management Studio, ele funciona. Porém, quando tento chamar o sp no meu repository, ele retorna: Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.

Comment: @cidadaox aí é outro erro na aplicação. Abra outra pergunta com as informações necessárias para que possamos ver o que pode ser feito para ajudá-lo

Comment: estou trabalhando com Spring, tinha esquecido das anotações Transactional e Modifying para informar que é uma query de alteração. Agora está perfeito, Muito obrigado amigo